# How to perform a comparison of values from an outside query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a list of team weightings based on picking 11 players (based on their outfield positions) from each team. Below is a screenshot of the list and its code:

```
    SELECT TeamID, SUM(PlayerWeighting) as TeamWeight
FROM (
    SELECT * FROM(
        SELECT pl.*,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY pl.TeamID, pl.Position ORDER BY NEWID()) AS Rnk
        FROM(
            SELECT DISTINCT p.PlayerID, p.Position, p.PlayerWeighting, p.FirstName, p.Surname, t.TeamID, t.TeamAbbreviation, f.WeekNumber
            FROM dbo.Fixture f
            INNER JOIN dbo.League l ON f.LeagueID = l.LeagueID
            INNER JOIN dbo.Team t ON l.LeagueID = t.LeagueID
            INNER JOIN dbo.Player p ON t.TeamID = p.TeamID
            WHERE f.WeekNumber = 1) 
            pl) po
    WHERE (po.position = 'GK' and po.rnk = 1) OR 
          (po.position = 'DF' and po.rnk <= 4) OR
          (po.position = 'MF' and po.rnk <= 4) OR
          (po.position = 'FW' and po.rnk <= 2) ) as T
GROUP BY T.TeamID
```

[image]

What I want to do is link each team with their opposition on a week by week basis. For example if you look at the fixture list below we have team 4 vs team 60. So I want to compare the teamWeight of team 4 against  the TeamWeight of team 60, the one with the highest wins (which I know can be done via CASE WHEN statement).

[image]

Then will want to compare team 14 with team 59, then team 15 with 43 and etc up to the last game for week 1 which is team 19 vs team 35.

It is should be on a week by week basis as using SQL Agent Job to run daily, so everytime the agent job executes, it will run a week of fixtures and increments to run the next week fixtures for the next time it runs. I know a parameter for week number needs to be set for this.

My question then is how to get the teams match up against each other when comparing team weightings. For this example lets say winning team (higher team weight) has 3 points inserted into home or away points in fixture table (based on if they're home or way), losing team gets 0 and if equal then 1 point each.

Thank you,

UPDATE:

Below displays the code that fully creates the fixture list:

```
    WITH League_Teams AS (
        -- Generate a unique-per-league index for each team that is between 0
        -- and the (number of teams - 1) and calculate the number of teams
        -- if this is an odd number then generate a fake team that's 0.
        SELECT TeamID AS id,
            LeagueID,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY LeagueID ORDER BY TeamID ) - 1 AS idx,
            0 AS is_fake,
            COUNT(1) OVER ( PARTITION BY LeagueID ) AS num_teams, 
            (COUNT(1) OVER ( PARTITION BY LeagueID ) % 2) AS num_fake
        FROM Team

        UNION ALL
        -- Insert a fake team if required
        SELECT 0,
            LeagueID,
            COUNT(1),
            1,
            COUNT(1),
            1
        FROM   Team
        GROUP BY LeagueID
        HAVING COUNT(1) % 2  > 0
    ),
    cte AS (
        -- Calculate round 1 games
        SELECT 
            idx AS home_idx,
            num_teams + num_fake - 1 - idx AS away_idx,
            1 AS week_number,

            LeagueID AS leagueID,
            num_teams AS num_teams,
            num_fake AS num_fake
        FROM   league_teams
        WHERE  2 * idx < num_teams

        UNION ALL

        --  Generate successive rounds with the two cases when the away team has the maximum index or otherwise.
        SELECT 
            CASE away_idx
            WHEN num_teams + num_fake - 1 THEN home_idx + 1
            ELSE (home_idx + 1) % (num_teams + num_fake -1)
            END,

            CASE away_idx
            WHEN num_teams + num_fake - 1 THEN away_idx
            ELSE (away_idx + 1) % (num_teams + num_fake - 1)
            END,
            week_number + 1,
            leagueID,
            num_teams,
            num_fake
        FROM  cte
        WHERE week_number < (num_teams + num_fake - 1)
    )
    INSERT INTO dbo.Fixture
    -- Join the cte results back to the League_Teams table to convert
    -- Indexes used in calculation back to the actual team ids.
    SELECT rn,
           week_number,
           DATEADD(week, week_number - 1, @StartFixtureWeek) AS WeekNumber,
           h.id,
           NULL,
           a.id,
           NULL,
           NULL,
           NULL,
           c.leagueid
    FROM (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY LeagueID, week_number)  AS rn,
            t.*
        FROM (
               -- Duplicate the results swapping home and away.
               SELECT week_number,
                      home_idx,
                      away_idx,
                      LeagueId
               FROM   cte

               UNION ALL

               SELECT week_number + num_teams + num_fake - 1,
                      away_idx,
                      home_idx,
                      LeagueId
               FROM   cte
        ) t
    ) c
    INNER JOIN League_Teams h  ON ( c.home_idx = h.idx AND c.leagueId = h.LeagueID )
    INNER JOIN League_Teams a ON ( c.away_idx = a.idx AND c.leagueId = a.LeagueID )
    ORDER BY rn;
```

UPDATE 2:

Below is the player table that contains playerWeightings which when calculated in the query first shown within this question, makes up the team weighting:

[image]

Comment: Do you still need help on this?

Comment: @mvisser Yes still stuck on this. I was working on other things and waiting until someone can hopefully provide an answer

Comment: I really need to understand your logic.  So firstly you want to create a fixture list right? So in your logic, how did you work out team 14 vs team 60. and also why does team 14 become a home fixture and team 60 is an away fixture?

Comment: Ok so in the fixture list you have teams who are within the same league (LeagueID) to play each other home and away. Now I used recursives in order to build the fixture list. I have applied the code in order to give each home and away team its own index and sorted the teams accordinly based on that

Comment: So then you dont want a fixture list.  But only to compare the Teamweight, for the week and the fixture? Am I right

Comment: @mvisser That is correct

Comment: is homescore/awayscore the teamweight?

Comment: @mvisser The TeamWeight is the actual 'TeamWeight' column shown in first screen shot. It is actually made up of picking 11 random players from a team, with each plaaying have their own player weighting. Add all playerWeightings together and you get the 'TeamWeighting'. The first query in the question calculates the team weighting by picking 11 players but out of those 11, there needs to be 1 GK, 4 DF, 4 MF and 2 FW, these are player's already assigned positions when inserted into the db. I included a screeenshot of dbo.Player so you can see the player weghtings

Comment: so for example if team 20 vs 30.  Team 20 Weighting is 110 and Team 30 Weighting is 112.  Then Team 30 wins and they get 3 points? If this is the case, it just seems so easy your request.  For all the T-SQL you already created, this must be the easiest part.  Or am I missing something?  Because Then I could just create you a Stored Procedure that must take in FixtureID, LeagueID and does an aggregation.

Comment: Yes that is it but the thing to remember is that it is only for a week by week basis. So in Week 1, Team 20 vs 30, Team 20 could have weighting of 110 and Team 30 has weighting of 112, but in week 2 when team 20 plays lets say Team 23 and Team 30 plays Team 15, we need to random select 11 players again for each team so that they have a different weighting for that week of fixtures.It may be simple and my mind is just thinking of a simple logic or code. Yeah have a go on which way you prefer to answer

Comment: Ok awesome.  Let me create the first part of the Stored Procedure and calculate the score for fixture by week. I will get this to you by tomorrow.  And then we can speak about Randomizing.

Comment: Cool,, thank you mvisser

Comment: Also what will help me if you can email me the schemas and some sample data.  my email is sirow08@gmail.com.

Comment: Ok, I will send you the schema script and outline the requirements fully so you know what needs to happen. There has been a slight change but will notify you in the email

Comment: Awesome. Let me know when you sent it.

Comment: Sent it now, there is a lot of info but ask me any question by email or SO if you need to. It will be a challenge but I think you may enjoy it. All data should already be inserted. My brain is just fried from working on this in the last 2 weeks.